# Count the amount of days an employee has performed a certain task in MySQL, where tasks have a start date and end date

Tags: mysql, sql, count, pivot

I'm looking to create a yearly overview of tasks that employees have performed.
Tasks are stored in a schedule table where each task has an identifier (e.g. 'ABC'), a starting date, and an end date.
The columns of this table thus are: id, employee, task, startDate, and endDate.

Some data could include:

| id | employee | task | startDate | endDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Mr. Anderson | ABC | 2023-01-05 | 2023-01-08 |
| 2 | Mr. Anderson | DEF | 2023-01-06 | 2023-01-07 |
| 3 | Ms. Beatrice | ABC | 2023-01-04 | 2023-01-06 |
| 4 | Mr. Anderson | ABC | 2023-01-10 | 2023-01-12 |

What I would like to do, is show a cross tab, where you have employees on the left, and the number of days these employees have performed every type of task in a given period of time (i.e. 2023).

So, the result would be:

| Employee | ABC | DEF |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Mr. Anderson | 7 | 2 |
| Ms. Beatrice | 3 | 0 |

I know how to COUNT the occurrence of every task for every employee, which I'm doing with something like:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM schedule 
WHERE employee='Mr. Anderson' AND task='ABC'
```

This gives me 2 because there are 2 entries in the database where Mr. Anderson performs ABC. However, he performs ABC for 4+3 days (end date included in the count), so the result should be 7.

Does anyone know how I can update my query to give me the wanted result?

A solution with PIVOT would be acceptable as well (I haven't yet figured out how to work with PIVOT, but if there's a more elegant way to do this (without doing the query for every employee and every task) then please, be my guest.

EDIT: Sorry, I'm on MySQL.

Comment: What DBMS you are using?

Comment: The endDate column is missing.

Comment: @jarlh, it's my fault when I edited the question, fixed.

Comment: Date arithmetic is different in just about every RDBMS, so; are you using SQL Server, MySQL, SQLite, PostgreSQL, etc?

Comment: MySQL, sorry that I forgot to mention this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `COUNT()` us `SUM()` and aggregate the number of days between the start and end dates.

While inside SQL, I do not recommend pivoting the data, that's best left outside of SQL.  So, aim for three columns; the employee, the task, and the sum of elapsed days.  *(Both the SQL language and the DBMS implementations are designed with this normalised structure in mind.)*

```
SELECT
  employee,
  task,
  SUM(DATEDIFF(endDate, startDate)+1)   total_days
FROM
  schedule
GROUP BY
  employee,
  task
```

The `+1` is needed because you've opted to use `inclusive` end dates.  *(Normally they'd be `exclusive`; the range between the 1st of Jan and the 1st of Jan should normally be 0 days)*

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your advice and your query. When I try to run it on my database, I'm getting an error: Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'DATEDIFF'

Comment: @LaurensSwart As I said, that's SQL Server syntax. I'll edit the answer for MySQL.

Comment: Ah right, sorry, I wasn't aware that SQL Server != MySQL :-) Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: SQL Server is a product owned by Microsoft, but MySQL is a product now owned by Oracle.

Comment: Ah I see. You edited your answer but the query looks unchanged to me?

Comment: @LaurensSwart `DATEDIFF(DAY, startDate, endDate)` *(SQL Server; how many Days from startDate to endDate)* became `DATEDIFF(endDate, startDate)` *(MySQL; what is endDate minus startDate, implicitly measured in days)*

Comment: Damn this query is fast :-D! I was querying COUNTs for every employee and every task, which took the page like 5 seconds to load. Now it's almost instantaneous. Thank you so much!

Comment: @LaurensSwart Each query you run has it's own overhead. Being able to query multiple employees / tasks at once is always going to be faster, even if badly written. SQL is all about *sets* of data.

Comment: Thanks again! Do you think you can also help me with a follow-up question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75067457/sum-amount-of-days-an-employee-performs-a-task-using-datediff-but-only-count-da